# Mysql use another table to translate value

Tags: mysql

table **user**

```
+-----+-------+----------+------------+
| id  |  name |  gender  |   computer |
+-----+-------+----------+------------+
| 1   |  ben  |     1    |       3    |
+-----+-------+----------+------------+
```

table **translate**

```
+-----+--------+
| id  |  trans |
+-----+--------+
| 1   |   boy  |
| 2   |   girl |
| 3   |   pc   |
| 4   |   mac  |
+-----+--------+
```

**final result**

```
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
| id  |  name |  gender  | computer |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
|  1  |  ben  |  boy     | pc       |
+-----+-------+----------+----------+
```

I have 2 tables, one is user's data, the other is translate.

I want to use translate table to translate user's gender & computer's values
anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`JOIN`**.

**Query**

```
 select 
   t1.`id`,
   t1.`name`,
   t2.`trans` as `gender`,
   t3.`trans` as `computer`
from `user` t1
join `translate` t2
on t1.`gender` = t2.`id`
join `translate` t3
on t1.`computer` = t3.`id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've presented this, it doesn't appear to be a translation problem (in the sense of language), but rather a standard database partition problem. A more standard solution would be to define your entities each in their own tables:

**user**

```
+-----+--------+------------+--------------+
| id  |  name  |  genderId  |  computerId  |
+-----+--------+------------+--------------+
| 1   |  ben   |     1      |       1      |
+-----+--------+------------+--------------+
```

**gender**

```
+-----+--------+
| id  |  name  |
+-----+--------+
| 1   |  boy   |
+-----+--------+
| 2   |  girl  |
+-----+--------+
```

**computer**

```
+-----+--------+
| id  |  name  |
+-----+--------+
| 1   |  pc    |
+-----+--------+
| 2   |  mac   |
+-----+--------+
```

...and then your query reads:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
INNER JOIN gender ON user.genderId = gender.id
INNER JOIN computer ON user.computerId = computer.id
```